# Applescript text parsing inside Pages App

Tags: applescript

I am scripting a Pages form template with applescript. I'm using the code from a tutorial found here: https://iworkautomation.com/pages/script-tags-placeholder-text.html

The script works fine, however, I need to be able to insert a list for some of the Placeholder text fields. My plan was to use a delimiter, and to split the string I'm using the code from here:https://erikslab.com/2007/08/31/applescript-how-to-split-a-string/

It seems that when you're inside a tell application pages block, that text item objects are special, and the normal way of parsing strings with delimiters will not work.

The error I recieve is "Pages got an error: document id "E1303B92-B79A-4786-841B-EC5F46ACB05D" doesn’t understand the “findAndReplaceInText” message."

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
tell application "Pages"
-- ...

        -- PROMPT USER FOR REPLACEMENT TEXT
        set searchString to ";;"
        set crlf to return & linefeed
        repeat with i from 1 to the count of uniqueTags
            set thisTag to item i of uniqueTags
            display dialog "Enter the replacement text for this tag:" & ¬
                return & return & thisTag default answer "" buttons ¬
                {"Cancel", "Skip", "OK"} default button 3
            copy the result to {button returned:buttonPressed, text returned:replacementString}
            if buttonPressed is "OK" then
                set replacementString to findAndReplaceInText(replacementString, searchString, crlf)
                set (every placeholder text whose tag is thisTag) to replacementString
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell

on findAndReplaceInText(theText, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSearchString
    set theTextItems to every text item of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theReplacementString
    set theText to theTextItems as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theText
end findAndReplaceInText
```

Comment: You used 'replacementString' and 'searchString' in the main script but 'theReplacementString' and 'theSearchString' in your handler. If you make them consistent, the script will at least run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that when you're inside a tell application pages block, that text item objects are special, and the normal way of parsing strings with delimiters will not work.

No, it's just a matter of target scope. This is legal:

```
on sayHowdy()
    display dialog "howdy"
end sayHowdy
sayHowdy()
```

This is not:

```
on sayHowdy()
    display dialog "howdy"
end sayHowdy
tell application "Finder"
    sayHowdy() -- error
end tell
```

To fix it, we need to tell the Finder that `sayHowdy` belongs to us, not to it. To do so, use `my`:

```
on sayHowdy()
    display dialog "howdy"
end sayHowdy
tell application "Finder"
    my sayHowdy()
end tell
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. I was confused when I put the code from the handler directly into the loop, and I got the same error. Am I correct in thinking that the scoping only works in a handler because of the pages text item object? Is there a way to scope the code inside the loop so that a handler isn't needed?

Comment: You didn’t show enough code to reproduce the issue. But you can always put a `tell me` block inside the `tell document 1` block or whatever it is.